# Can there be scenarios, where a function defined by setTimeout won't be executed before the next tick?

Tags: node.js

I am reading https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/understanding-process-nexttick/ and the last sentence is:

> Use nextTick() when you want to make sure that in the next event loop iteration that code is already executed.

But before that, it says:

> Calling setTimeout(() => {}, 0) will execute the function at the end of next tick, much later than when using nextTick() which prioritizes the call and executes it just before the beginning of the next tick.

Now I'm a bit confused, why should I use `nextTick()` to make sure code has been executed before the next tick? Is code defined in `setTimeout()` not guaranteed to be executed?

Answer (score -1):

**setTimeout(() => {}, 0)** will execute the function much later than **nextTick()**

> setTimeout(() => {}, 0) it takes time to execute, you can see difference in output below.

```
//setTimeout  
setTimeout(() => {
console.log('Executed this in the next iteration');
}, 0);
console.log('Executed this in the current iteration');

//See Output ----->
Executed this in the current iteration
connected to port: 2020
Executed this in the next iteration
```

> nextTick() prioritizes the call and executes it just before the beginning of the next tick.

```
//nextTick
process.nextTick(() => {
 console.log('Executed this in the next iteration');
});
console.log('Executed this in the current iteration');

//See Output ----->
Executed this in the current iteration
Executed this in the next iteration
connected to port: 2020
```